# How to make post requests with webview?

Tags: android, webview, http-post, response

I want to make an http post request using webview.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,
                String url) {

            webView.postUrl(Base_Url, postData.getBytes());

            return true;
            }

        });
```

The above code snippet loads the webpage. I want to access the response of this request.

How can i obtain the response of an http post request using webview?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: there is no role of webView in this scenario , webView simply lets your webpage display in the android gadgets , now its uoto you to handle the request response in your website on the server site , i would suggest you use HTTPPOST calls to take the response

Comment: Your question is: How to make post requests with web view?
Than in details you ask: How can i obtain the response of an http post request using web view? So what is your real question? Hence my down vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The WebView does not let you access the content of the HTTP response.

You have to use [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) for that, and then forward the content to the view by using the function [loadDataWithBaseUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and specifying the base url so that the user can use the webview to continue navigating in the website.

Example:

```
// Executing POST request
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setEntity(postContent);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

// Get the response content
String line = "";
StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
    contentBuilder.append(line); 
}
String content = contentBuilder.toString();

// Do whatever you want with the content

// Show the web page
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, content, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: how can i use http post request with loadDataWithBaseUrl?

Comment: I add an example to the answer

Answer (score 12):

First add the support of the http library to your gradle file:
To be able to use

`useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

After this you can use the following code to perform post request in your webview:

```
public void postUrl (String url, byte[] postData)
String postData = "submit=1&id=236";
webview.postUrl("http://www.belencruzz.com/exampleURL",EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

http://belencruz.com/2012/12/do-post-request-on-a-webview-in-android/

Comment: EncodingUtils is deprecated and cant be used

Comment: @war_Hero what is the alternative for EncodingUtils

Comment: URLEncoder.encode returns a string, not a byte[]. Would calling .getBytes() on it work?