# Grabbing post parameters in android WebView

Tags: android, ios, uiwebviewdelegate

In IOS ,we have a delegate method  `"shouldStartLoadWithRequest"`to grab post parameters in UIWebView as described in

[Grabbing POST data from UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457749/grabbing-post-data-from-uiwebview)

I couldn't find any such method for Android on googling. In Android ,I am able to handle this by javascriptinterface where server provides me the post parameters. But I don't want this.So please help with below query :

Is there any such similar method in Android to grab post parameters ? Or should I stick with the previous approach ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this post if that's what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6290178/1342638

Comment: @red_alert Here in the post, postData is created at our side.I need to grab the post parameters sent  with Url loaded in webview. vj

Comment: Ok. I think the workaround for that is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13452533/1342638

You can't access directly the HTTP requests of a web view, you need to make a request to the url before and getting the POST values that you want...

Comment: It means we must grab post parameters from server or create our own and then integrate to url. Then,call view.posturl(url,postparameters).